# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, runtime, jscript

I am working on this code but I am getting the following error,

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
.innerContent.children(.innerContentP).children(label)

--JS--

```
$(".innerContent").children(".innerContentP").children("label").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().children("span").slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: describe what you are trying to do, maybe there is a way to write the code more simple.

Comment: jQuery version and internet explorer version used

Comment: its simple code to popup a absolute div with some parent, children relationship. it works well if run the html but c#.net its throwing this error..

Comment: i am using jquery 1.9.1 version of jquery

Comment: You somehow got the quotes stripped from your script - view a page source.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run JavaScript like you do it in a browser, but in a .Net environment. JavaScript is a language, it has a scope. In a browser, your scope is one thing, in .Net it's another one. jQuery uses variables from browser scope, so to use it with .Net you need tools like this - http://jqueryfordotnet.codeplex.com/

Read about Microsoft JScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1s0ezse(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: this doesn't explain why they're getting a _syntax_ error - the syntax is the same across platforms, isn't it?

Comment: I guess it's related somehow. Not sure though, but GuruNoola is going to meet another problems anyway if he don't figure out the scope question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution, it was the way i am adding the click event to the selector

the correct way i figured out instead of
    $(".innerContent").children(".innerContentP").children("label").click(function(){
     //code here });

```
is 

$(".innerContent .innerContentP label").click(function(){ //code here });
```

and worked well.

if any one can explain the reason ill be greatful